# How to make container with main content wider in Jekyll Time Machine theme?

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I am using the Jekyll Time Machine theme on GitHub and would like to make the main content section a lot wider:

https://ieg-dhr.github.io/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/

I have checked the *[stylesheet.css](https://github.com/ieg-dhr/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/blob/main/stylesheets/stylesheet.css)* file but cannot find the right settings.

The following code seems to relate to the overall page background rather than the "box" that contains the text and images:

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
  background: #ddd url(../images/pattern.png);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #b1b1b1;
}
```

I have posted an issue in the developer's repository but have not received a response so far. So if anyone is using *Time Machine*, too, I am very grateful for your help.

**EDIT:**

As opposed to other themes I have used before, I am generally finding Time Machine hard to customize. I am also struggling with column width in tables.

The Github display of my page shows what I want (different column sizes and table widths):

https://github.com/ieg-dhr/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/blob/main/README.md

But in the Time Machine deployment, they are all the same:

https://ieg-dhr.github.io/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/

Answer (score 0):

The Time Machine jekyll theme sets the width of the main content to `width: 675px;` [1]. I can see in your stylesheet.css is setting the width to `100%` [2], which I believe resolves to Time Machine's `width: 675px;`.

I think you will want to edit your stylesheet.css to override the width from the Time Machine theme.

[1] https://github.com/pages-themes/time-machine/blob/master/_sass/jekyll-theme-time-machine.scss#L37-L40

[2] https://github.com/ieg-dhr/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/blob/main/stylesheets/stylesheet.css#L461-L464

Comment: I tried setting it to 200% and that did not make a difference either. I will now try and hard-code with width > 675px.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looking for a solution here.
In your `github` site the problem is the name of the file

```
/assets/css/style.css
```

which should be

```
/assets/css/style.scss
```

see
https://github.com/pages-themes/time-machine/tree/master#stylesheet